# Server slow because of exhaustive MySQL usage

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, replication

**Short description of my website:** It's an advertising network similar to BuySellAds. Publishers register and create adspaces for their websites, advertisers can then choose which adspace they want to advertise on.

**This is how it works:** Advertiser uploads an ad and then purchases any adspace for a given time. When visiting the publisher website the ad will show in the adspace.

**A few things need to happen to have the site running:**

- Interface for advertisers to upload banners and purchase exposure time;
- Ad server that delivers all ads and collects statistics (visitors, clicks, etc...);
- Script that runs on a cronjob as fast as possible to update users balances (it's currently running every 1-5 minutes, ideally it would be an endless cicle);
- Another script to process statistics from data gathered from adserver.

Currently, I'm using only one VPS for everything, so as you can imagine it's pretty unresponsible, it's slow when cronjobs are running and sometimes crashes.

**Ideally I think there should be 4 servers for best performance:**

- Frontend
- Ad server
- Stats processing server
- Balances proessing server ($$)

Where the frontend would only deal with the interface for publishers and advertisers, the adserver would deliver the ads and gather data, the stats processing would process the data and the balances processing server would credit users balances and stop ads when the balance reaches 0.

I've tried with master/slaves replications but I couldn't make it work the way I want because all 4 servers need read/write previleges.

What would you do?

Comment: This question is quite honestly unanswerable. There could be a magnitude of reasons why it is slow and unresponsive. You haven't provided *any* information to help identify what might be the cause. Profile your queries, profile your servers performance, memory usage, cpu cycles etc - Until you identify what is slowing it down you simply cannot possible address and resolve any performance issues.

Comment: @Steve The performance issue is having the stats and balances processing script on the same VPS.

Comment: that is s start, you know 'what' is the cause, now you need to figure out 'why'. Is it the query, disk IO, resource usage, poor indexing, greedy statements or the other thousands of possible reasons it could be? - at the very least you should provide the script (or a simple version), an explain, your DDL and crash errors, profiling results etc

Comment: @Steve Whenever the balance processing script fires up all 8 CPU cores to do 99% and the rest of the site gets very slow. I've tried to make pauses at the end of every cicle with usleep() and it got a little better but it's still pretty slow. I've also tried to change the priority to 19 with nice but didn't change much. I've searched for hours for a way to limit the script for 4 CPU cores but didn't find anything that could help.

Comment: @Steve I hate wasting 90% of my time with server configurations rather than actually developing the site.

Answer (score 1):

I would optimize the way you process data. Why would you calculate statistics if no one reads them? So, before you think about engaging more servers maybe:

- Create statistics only on user demand and do not create all at once.
  You can also delay this if server is busy, on client side it is not a disaster
- On ad delivery also calculate user balance
- Optimize your tables and queries

All of these is possible and you should not have problems for implementation. You will have problems if you place ads on websites with 3M visits per day - than you should think of alternatives and maybe do delayed inserts or other solutions you find on net. But I am sure if you get few million requests per day using one server - it will die, not because it can't handle it, but because 90% will come in 2-3 hours.

Comment: Last 30 days the server delivered 370M page views (6.2 TB total bandwidth) and it's increasing fast. Statistics are shown to advertisers so they know which is the best space to buy. The code is already optimized to oblivion, I really think the only option here is to distribute tasks between servers.

Comment: Just trying to brainstorm this, try to do calculations on client side and only on demand. You can also try to divide your cron jobs and relax the server.